# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having an issue with the below mentioned sql query.
Basically I am trying to list all the system users that have captured data in the current week and previous week for each day.

Problem with my query below I get the "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
". I have changed a part of this query to uses EXISTS but still get the same error on the last line of the subquery.

```
DECLARE @Dates date;
SET @Dates = '20091012';
DECLARE @FirstDayOfWeek date;
DECLARE @lastDayOfWeek date;

SET @FirstDayOfWeek = dbo.[fn_GetFirstDayOfWeek](@Dates);
SET @lastDayOfWeek = DATEADD(day, 6,@FirstDayOfWeek);

SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT DISTINCT q.CapturerId, u.Firstname, u.Lastname INTO #Users
from Wop_Questionnaires q JOIN
        Frwk_Users u
    ON
        q.CapturerId = u.Id JOIN
    Core_Areas a  ON 
    u.X_Wop_ProvinceId = a.Id

WHERE u.X_Wop_ProvinceId = 5



SELECT (SELECT #Users.Firstname+' '+#Users.Lastname, COUNT(q.CapturerId) 
    from Wop_Questionnaires q  JOIN #Users on q.CapturerId = #Users.CapturerId 
    where EXISTS(SELECT #Users.CapturerID from #Users WHERE q.CapturerId = #Users.CapturerId) 
    AND q.CaptureDate >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',@FirstDayOfWeek),'19000101')
    And q.CaptureDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',@FirstDayOfWeek)+1,'19000101')
    GROUP BY q.CapturerId, #Users.Firstname,#Users.Lastname) Sun,
(SELECT #Users.Firstname+' '+#Users.Lastname, COUNT(q.CapturerId) 
    from Wop_Questionnaires q  JOIN #Users on q.CapturerId = #Users.CapturerId 
    where EXISTS (SELECT #Users.CapturerID from #Users WHERE q.CapturerId = #Users.CapturerId) 
    AND q.CaptureDate >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,1,@FirstDayOfWeek)),'19000101')
    AND q.CaptureDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,1,@FirstDayOfWeek))+1,'19000101')
    GROUP BY q.CapturerId, #Users.Firstname,#Users.Lastname) Mon,
(SELECT #Users.Firstname+' '+#Users.Lastname, COUNT(q.CapturerId) 
    from Wop_Questionnaires q  JOIN #Users on q.CapturerId = #Users.CapturerId 
    where EXISTS(SELECT #Users.CapturerID from #Users WHERE q.CapturerId = #Users.CapturerId) 
    AND q.CaptureDate >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,2,@FirstDayOfWeek)),'19000101')
    AND q.CaptureDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,2,@FirstDayOfWeek))+1,'19000101')
    GROUP BY q.CapturerId, #Users.Firstname,#Users.Lastname) Tue;


--;--

DROP TABLE #Users;
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Thanks
Tebogo

Answer (score 0):

Convert to the following?

```
SELECT... GROUP BY Sun 
UNION 
SELECT... GROUP BY Mon 
UNION 
SELECT ... GROUP BY Tue
```

Probably not the most efficient answer, but should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually need to have the users daily totals in one row. I need to count all the entries that a user in a certain region has done daily Sun - Sat, all listed in one row per user.

Have been trying out some couple of angles around it but still struggling 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have revised my sql to look like the following: There's probably a much cleaner and efficient way to do this. I am using a Pivot to arrive the desired result.

Excuse the long code.

```
DECLARE @Dates date;
SET @Dates = '20091015';
DECLARE @FirstDayOfWeek date;
DECLARE @lastDayOfWeek date;

SET @FirstDayOfWeek = dbo.[fn_GetFirstDayOfWeek](@Dates);
SET @lastDayOfWeek = DATEADD(day, 6,@FirstDayOfWeek);

SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT q.CapturerId, u.Firstname+' '+u.Lastname Name INTO #Userss
from Wop_Questionnaires q JOIN
        Frwk_Users u
    ON
        q.CapturerId = u.Id JOIN
    Core_Areas a  ON 
    u.X_Wop_ProvinceId = a.Id

WHERE u.X_Wop_ProvinceId = 5
select #Userss.CapturerId  from #Userss
CREATE TABLE #Final(Name Varchar(50),cDay VARCHAR(50), NumRecs int);

INSERT INTO #Final(Name, cDay, NumRecs)
SELECT #Userss.Name,'Sun' as cDay, q.CapturerId NumRecs
    from Wop_Questionnaires q  JOIN #Userss on q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId 
    where q.CapturerId IN(SELECT #Userss.CapturerID from #Userss) 
    AND q.CaptureDate >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',@FirstDayOfWeek),'19000101')
    And q.CaptureDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',@FirstDayOfWeek)+1,'19000101')
    GROUP BY  #Userss.Name, q.CapturerId

    UNION ALL

SELECT #Userss.Name,'Mon' as cDay, q.CapturerId NumRecs  
    from Wop_Questionnaires q  JOIN #Userss on q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId 
    where EXISTS (SELECT #Userss.CapturerID from #Userss WHERE q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId) 
    AND q.CaptureDate >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,1,@FirstDayOfWeek)),'19000101')
    AND q.CaptureDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,1,@FirstDayOfWeek))+1,'19000101')
    GROUP BY #Userss.Name, q.CapturerId

    UNION ALL

SELECT #Userss.Name,'Tue' cDay, q.CapturerId NumRecs
    from Wop_Questionnaires q  JOIN #Userss on q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId 
    where EXISTS(SELECT #Userss.CapturerID from #Userss WHERE q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId) 
    AND q.CaptureDate >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,2,@FirstDayOfWeek)),'19000101')
    AND q.CaptureDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,2,@FirstDayOfWeek))+1,'19000101')
    GROUP BY #Userss.Name, q.CapturerId

    UNION ALL

SELECT #Userss.Name,'Wed' cDay, q.CapturerId NumRecs
    from Wop_Questionnaires q  JOIN #Userss on q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId 
    where EXISTS(SELECT #Userss.CapturerID from #Userss WHERE q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId) 
    AND q.CaptureDate >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,3,@FirstDayOfWeek)),'19000101')
    AND q.CaptureDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,3,@FirstDayOfWeek))+1,'19000101')
    GROUP BY #Userss.Name, q.CapturerId


    UNION ALL

SELECT #Userss.Name,'Thur' cDay, q.CapturerId NumRecs
    from Wop_Questionnaires q  JOIN #Userss on q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId 
    where EXISTS(SELECT #Userss.CapturerID from #Userss WHERE q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId) 
    AND q.CaptureDate >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,4,@FirstDayOfWeek)),'19000101')
    AND q.CaptureDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,4,@FirstDayOfWeek))+1,'19000101')
    GROUP BY #Userss.Name, q.CapturerId 


    UNION ALL

SELECT #Userss.Name,'Fri' cDay, q.CapturerId NumRecs
    from Wop_Questionnaires q  JOIN #Userss on q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId 
    where EXISTS(SELECT #Userss.CapturerID from #Userss WHERE q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId) 
    AND q.CaptureDate >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,5,@FirstDayOfWeek)),'19000101')
    AND q.CaptureDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,5,@FirstDayOfWeek))+1,'19000101')
    GROUP BY #Userss.Name, q.CapturerId


    UNION ALL

SELECT #Userss.Name,'Sat' cDay, q.CapturerId NumRecs
    from Wop_Questionnaires q  JOIN #Userss on q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId 
    where EXISTS(SELECT #Userss.CapturerID from #Userss WHERE q.CapturerId = #Userss.CapturerId) 
    AND q.CaptureDate >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,6,@FirstDayOfWeek)),'19000101')
    AND q.CaptureDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',DATEADD(DAY,6,@FirstDayOfWeek))+1,'19000101')
    GROUP BY #Userss.Name, q.CapturerId 

--SELECT * from #Final;
--;--*/

SELECT  Name,
        [Sun] as [Sun],
        [Mon] as [Mon],
        [Tue] as [Tue],
        [Wed] as [Wed],
        [Thur] as [Thur],
        [Fri] as [Fri],
        [Sat] as [Sat],
        [Sun]+[Mon]+[Tue]+[Wed]+[Thur]+[Fri]+[Sat] as Total
FROM (SELECT Name, cDay, NumRecs FROM #Final) as Src
PIVOT (Count(NumRecs) For cDay IN ([Sun],[Mon],[Tue],[Wed],[Thur],[Fri],[Sat])) as Pvt
ORDER BY Name

DROP TABLE #Userss;
DROP TABLE #Final;
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```